# jquery, adding and removing event handlers

Tags: jquery, events, addeventlistener

I have 2 buttons

```
 $(".button1").on("click", function(event){
 $(".button2").on("click", function(event){
```

What I would like to do is start with button1 as clicked and have no event listener, when button2 is clicked the event listener is removed and the event listener for button 1 is activated.

This is a fairly common technique is in actionscript 3 with the method removeEventListener() and would like to use a similar method or technique in jquery.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to remove an event handler bound with `jQuery.on` then you probably want `jQuery.off`

http://api.jquery.com/off/

Answer (score 5):

`on()` method bind event and `off()` unbind it. If you give parameter to `off()` it will unbind only supplied event, but without parameter unbind all events.

```
    $('.button1').on('click', function() {
        console.log('button1');
        $(this).off('click');
        $('.button2').on('click');
    })
    $('.button2').on('click', function() {
         console.log('button2');
        $(this).off('click');
        $('.button1').on('click');
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have but it does not put the event listener back on

```
 $(".slide1").on("click", function(){
    $(this).addClass('on');
    $('.slide2').removeClass('on');
     $(this).off('click');
    $('.slide2').on('click');
});

$(".slide2").on("click", function(){
    $(this).addClass('on');
    $('.slide1').removeClass('on');
    $(this).off('click');
    $('.slide1').on('click');
});
```